# Remove values in an array

Tags: arrays, perl

This is our array :

```
my @array = ('?C=N;O=D',
'?C=M;O=A',
'?C=S;O=A',
'?C=D;O=A',
'/lab/blog/wp-content/',
'1-list.txt',
'2014/',
'2015/',
'rbxslider/',
'slideshow-gallery/',
'uigen_2015/'
);
```

how to remove all values before `</lab/blog/wp-content/>` value

```
shift @list until (shift (@list)=~m/wp-contnet/);
```

i have tried with this way but no result

Comment: Where are you getting this array. It looks like you're parsing something.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
@array = grep /wp-content/../(?!)/, @array;
```

Comment: How does this work? What is the purpose of `(?!)` for example?

Comment: it's using `..` in its role as a flipflop operator; it returns false until the left operand is true, then true until after the right operand is true. `/(?!)/` is just an arbitrary regex that is always false.  you can't just say `/foo/..0` because if one of the operands is a constant (or folds to a constant), it implicitly does a comparison against `$.` as if you'd said `/foo/..($.==0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Close.

```
shift @array until $array[0] =~ /wp-content/;
```

Or if there's a chance that there might not be anything to remove,

```
while ($array[0] !~ /wp-content/) { shift @array; }
```

You might want to make sure you don't loop forever.

```
while (@array && $array[0] !~ /wp-content/) { shift @array; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, when you use the proper array name and correct the typo in "wp-content", but that doesn't include the 'wp-content' element which appears as though you'd like to do. The following checks the first element before shifting, instead of shifting it off and then checking it:

```
if (grep /wp-content/, @array){
    shift @array until $array[0] =~ /wp-content/;
}

print "$_\n" for @array;
```

Output:

```
    /lab/blog/wp-content/
    1-list.txt
    2014/
    2015/
    rbxslider/
    slideshow-gallery/
    uigen_2015/
```

Comment: that will endlessly loop if it doesn't find the string in any element

Answer (score 0):

```
my $count = 0;
my @keep;
foreach (@array){
    $count++ if m|/lab/blog/wp-content/|;
    push @keep, $_ if $count > 0;
}
say foreach @keep;
```

---

```
/lab/blog/wp-content/
1-list.txt
2014/
2015/
rbxslider/
slideshow-gallery/
uigen_2015/
```